# How to test if two cLogit coefficients are significantly different

Tags: r, regression

I have the output of a cLogit test as shown below, but how do you test if the coefficients of two attributes are significantly different from each other?

[image]

I have been playing with `linearHypothesis()` from the `car` package but I dont know whether this is correct for a clogit model. The alternative would be to change the baseline attribute to one of the attributes of interest and redo the model but this seems to be the long way around.